# Exception running multi-project Solution in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to build an Android application using C# in Visual Studio 2022.  I've successfully deployed the APK from this solution, but I never get to actually debug the project where the code is being executed.

Here's the code that is being executed:

```
 base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
 Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
 LoadApplication(new App());
```

The application loads with a blank screen and I get this error, which I can't find anyone who has had a issue with Xamarin.Forms:

> {System.FormatException: UnexpectedToken "True" into 0
> at Xamarin.Forms.Shapes.PathFigureCollectionConverter.ThrowBadToken () [0x00000]

I can't find any reference to PathFigureCollectionConverter having this method.

I do use some Xamarin Forms Shapes, but I would appreciate any assistance in getting to the place where I need a change.

Obviously, I'm supposed to be using 0 instead of true, but my thought is something else could be wrong, since I'm not able to see the code where the exception is thrown.

I'm a newbie at Android development, so your patience would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can tried to debug to find which line caused this error at first.  In addition, this is the code in my MainActivity `protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }`.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I tried to debug, but was unable to- I couldn't determine the location to put a breakpoint.  I got no response to this question so I went ahead and created a fresh project and imported my code and got past it finally.